# report builder 3.0 date timestamp expression

Tags: datetime, timestamp, expression, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report that uses the folowing expression in a date timestamp field to format the date as either US format or European format depending on a Language prompt the user selects:

```
=iif(Parameters!LANG.Value = "EN", ToDateTime(Fields!TRANS_DATE.Value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), ToDateTime(Fields!TRANS_DATE.Value).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

If he user selects English, April 1st appears as 04/01/16.  If they select any other format, the date appears as 01-04-16.  Works great.

I would like to do the same thing on another field but I would like to leave the time in the results.  So, if the user selects English, the results would display 04-01-16 11:15:23 AM.  Otherwise, I would like to see 01-04-16 11:15:23 AM.

Can I modify the expression above to do the same thing but leave the hours and minutes and seconds in the result?

Thanks for your help.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append this to your datetime format string:

```
"hh:mm:ss tt"
```

So in your case:

```
=iif(Parameters!LANG.Value = "EN", ToDateTime(Fields!TRANS_DATE.Value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"), ToDateTime(Fields!TRANS_DATE.Value).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"))
```

Comment: @Tomas_Stibrany.........Thanks.  That worked.  I appreciate your help with this.....